# Inheritance and arraylist in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, arraylist, super

I am trying to create a java program where I have a parent class `MotorVehicle` and many different sub classes namely `Car`, `Bus`, and `Truck`. Now, `MotorVehicle` has 6 data members and each of the other classes have 2 different data members each.

In my main method, I created an `ArrayList<MotorVehicle> myArrayList` and I create objects of `Car`, `Bus`, and `Truck`and add them to this arraylist. So for example, for `car` I do:

```
Car newCar = new Car (all, the, parameters, common, and, class, specific);
myArrayList.add(newCar);
```

Similarly for `Bus`, and for `Truck`. During execution, I saw that the new instances or entries into the arraylist were overwriting the MotorVehicle parameters for the existing items.
So for example: If I have an exisitng `Car` instance in the list. And then I add a `Bus` instance, the 6 data members of the `Bus` instance pertaining to the `MotorVehicle` class overwrite the 6 data members of the existing `Car` instance pertaining to the `MotorVehicle` class.

I thought it might get fixed by doing this (but sadly, it did not):

```
MotorVehicle newCar = new Car (all, the, parameters, common, and, class, specific);
```

**That is by changing the type to MotorVehicle**

Also in the respective classes, I have a constructor that is defined as following: Car for example:

```
public Car(all, the, parameters, common, and, class, specific){
    super(all the 6 data members of the MotorVehicle class);
    //Set the local variables - specific to Car
}
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong?

**CAR.java** *: the car class*

```
public class Car extends MotorVehicle{
private int numberDoors;
private String color;

public Car(){

}

public Car(int numberDoors, String color){
    setNumberDoors(numberDoors);
    setCarColor(color);
}

/*
Need to add date
*/
public Car(String vehicleType, int numberWheels, double engineSize, boolean powerSteering, String purchaseDate, int numberDoors, String color, String serialNumber){        
    super(vehicleType, numberWheels, engineSize, powerSteering, purchaseDate, serialNumber);
    setNumberDoors(numberDoors);
    setCarColor(color);
}

private void setNumberDoors(int numberDoors) {
    this.numberDoors = numberDoors;
}

public int getNumberDoors(){
    return numberDoors;
}

private void setCarColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

private String getCarColor(){
    return color;
}

public String toString(){
    //Does printing
}
}
```

**MotorVehicle.java** *: the parent class*

```
 public  class MotorVehicle {
    static private String vehicleType;
    static private int numberWheels;
    static private double engineSize;
    static private boolean powerSteering;
    static private String purchaseDate;
        static private String serialNumber;


    //null constructor
     public MotorVehicle()
     {

     }
         //constructor with single parameter of type string
     public MotorVehicle ( String vehicleType)
     {
         setVehicleType(vehicleType);
     }
         //constructor with five parameters of type string, integer, double, boolean
     public MotorVehicle(String vehicleType, int numberWheels,double engineSize,boolean powerSteering, String
             purchaseDate, String serialNumber)
     {
         setVehicleType(vehicleType);
         setNumberWheels(numberWheels);
         setEngineSize(engineSize);
         setPowerSteering(powerSteering);
         setPurchaseDate(purchaseDate);
                 setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
     }
    public void setVehicleType (String vehicleType )
     {
         this.vehicleType=vehicleType;
     }
     static public String getVehicleType ()
     {
         return vehicleType;
     }

     public void setNumberWheels (int numberWheels)
     {
         this.numberWheels=numberWheels;
     }

     static public int getNumberWheels()
     {
         return numberWheels;
     }

     public void setEngineSize( double engineSize)
     {
         this.engineSize=engineSize;
     }

     static public double getEngineSize( )
     {
         return engineSize;

     }
     public void setPowerSteering (boolean powerSteering)
     {
         this.powerSteering=powerSteering;
     }

     static public boolean getPowerSteering()
     {
         return powerSteering;
     }

     public void setPurchaseDate (String purchaseDate )
     {
         this.purchaseDate=purchaseDate;
     }

     static public String getPurchaseDate ()
     {
         return purchaseDate; 

     }

         public void setSerialNumber (String serialNumber)
     {
         this.serialNumber=serialNumber;
     }

     static public String getSerialNumber()
     {
return serialNumber;
     }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
//Does printing
    }
    }
```

**Add function** *: in the main class*

```
add(ArrayList<MotorVehicle> myArrayList)
{
    System.out.print("Enter vehicle type- CAR, BUS, TRUCK, OTHER: ");
    type = sc.next();
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Car")) {
        int wheels = 0, doors = 0;
        String date = "", color = "", serialNo = "";
        boolean powerSteering = false;
        double eSize = 0.0;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of wheels: ");
        wheels = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the enginer size in cc: ");
        eSize = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter true for power steering else false: ");
        powerSteering = sc.nextBoolean();

        System.out.print("Enter the purchase date as mm/dd/yyyy: ");
        date = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the vehicle serial number: ");
        serialNo = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of doors: ");
        doors = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the car's color: ");
        color = sc.next();

        MotorVehicle newCar = new Car("Car", wheels, eSize, powerSteering, date, doors, color, serialNo);
        myArrayList.add(newCar);
}
```

Comment: Provide the necessary code to replicate your problem.

Comment: cast the value you get when you try to acces it from your list

Comment: Also, looks like you declared fields in these classes as `static`. Is that so?

Comment: I have emailed you, @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @jhamon casting is not the issue.

Comment: Don't email me. Instead [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26976929/edit) the question and provide the code there.

Comment: @jhamon, I looked at the variables by debugging. The issue is in adding the item itself.

Comment: as Luggui wrote, please provide more code

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What all classes do I share? And yes I had to make them static to access the variables in a toString method that I created.

Comment: your last comment seems very strange

Comment: @jhamon I initially tried printing them and looking at it, and I thought it was a casting error. Then I put it into debug mode and saw, the values were modified as soon as a new isntance was added.

Comment: As suspected, your fields were marked as `static`. Remove that declaration. Also, change the `private` fields in the super class to `protected`.

Comment: And again, **please don't email me with your code**. Instead, provide the necessary code to replicate the problem here in the question.

Comment: So how do I access the parameters in my toString method for different classes?

Comment: *change the `private` fields in the super class to `protected`*.

Comment: even after making it protected, it complains
**non static cannot be referenced from a static context**

Comment: Because you haven't removed `static` from the getter methods... Geez...

Comment: I already did that... I removed all "static" from the parent class. Also, removing static has fixed that. I just need to understand how to access the parent class data members in the child class without making them static..

Comment: I got it, I got it. I just had to remove **MotorVehicle.** from every method access.
Thank you so much for your help and bearing up with my naive nature @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the fields are static, as you have commented.
When you have a static variable in a class, it has the same value for all instances. For example, if you have `Car c1` and `Car c2` and set `c1.field1 = "foo"`, the value of `field1` will be `"foo"` for both `c1` and `c2`.
So, what you must do is make these fields non static.